# Event Log time when Computer Start up / boot up

Tags: windows, windows-xp, eventviewer

Client OS - Window XP

Domain Controller:- Window server 2008 Standard R2

I had one Windows XP system. I want to find out when the system has started or boot ( at what time and date ). I don't know which parameter / word should I search for in Event Log.

For finding out shutdown time, I simply find the word "Shutdown" in Event Log.

Can you guide me which word should I should search for to determine Start up or boot time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## EventViewer ( System Log )

6009 and 6005 same time stamp, system just started.

6013 - system has been up for a day or more, time in seconds.

6006 - the system was rebooted or shutdown.

## PowerShell: Get All Reboot Messages in the Last Month

```perl
Get-EventLog -LogName System -After $(Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) | Where { 6009,6005,6006 -contains $_.EventID}
```

Comment: the above powershell works great, thanks a lot

Comment: This answer is no longer complete because in Windows 10, events 6009 and 6005 are not always logged if a user clicks "Shut Down" from the Start Menu and then turns on the computer by pressing the power button.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the message saying the event log has started.

Event 6005
Event Log Service has started

Or Event 6009 with info about the OS build, service peck level, etc.